# Picasa picture upload with GDATA API over OAuth1.0

Tags: oauth, gdata, gdata-api, picasa

I have been trying to use the GDATA APIs for Picasa, with OAuth1.0
Though I am able read all the information, image upload is failing with **HTTP error 400:Bad Request**.
Can someone show me a working example of image upload using OAuth1.0+GDATA?